# Reading data from excel into a vector

Tags: arrays, excel, clojure

How do i read in data from csv files into a vector of vectors.

In other words each row would be a vector and each column would be an element inside the vector. 
It would be like a 2D array [row][col]

Comment: Why the parsed CSV table output does not suit you?

Comment: You already asked about reading from csv file and you have the solution with clojure.data.csv. Did you try that library?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use an existing csv library, like [clojure-csv](https://github.com/davidsantiago/clojure-csv) or [data.csv](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv).

data.csv for example is as easy as

```
(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv]
         '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(with-open [in-file (io/reader "in-file.csv")]
  (doall
    (csv/read-csv in-file)))
```

(Example taken from [here](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv#example-usage))

`csv/read-csv` will return a lazy sequence of vectors, which you could transform to a vector of vectors of strings using `vec` (if you really want).